# printing arabic on zebra ZM400 , the characters appear separated

Tags: arabic, zpl

```
^XA
^FO32,23
^A@E:TT0003M_.TTF,N,23,32
^PA1,1,1,1
^FH
^CI28
^FD_D9_85_D8_AD_D8_A7_D9_83_D9_85_D8_A9
^FS
^XZ
```

I am using the above code to print arabic on  a zebra printer ZM400  but the characters appear separated instead of connected " م ح ا ك م ة"   it should appear like this 
محاكمة

please help

Answer (score 2):

It work for me try use this command:

```
^XA^CI28^FT50,200^A@N,25,25,E:TT0003M_.TTF^PA1,1,1,1^FH^FD fff شامل الضريبة المضافة^FS^XZ
```

see the link [here](https://developer.zebra.com/thread/35910#comment-46065)